# error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker

I am start docker using this command:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd --bip=172.30.224.1/21 --ip-masq=false --mtu=1450 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

when I using `docker ps` command to list running docker process:

```
[root@ops001 work]# docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this? This is my version info:

```
[root@ops001 work]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Release:    7.6.1810
Codename:   Core
[root@ops001 work]# docker -v
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
[root@ops001 work]#
```

this is the host flannel ip info:

```
flannel.1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 172.30.224.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:b0:cc:7e:ba:ae  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2124  bytes 417113 (407.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2420  bytes 223879 (218.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify a list of sockets to listen to. Try this:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --bip=172.30.224.1/21 --ip-masq=false --mtu=1450 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

to configure Docker daemon to listen using Unix socket.

See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this happened because I'm using Rancher Desktop and had it configured to use containerd instead of docker. Once switched, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

try to run docker as service could solve this, on my CentOS, it should be:

```
systemctl start docker
```

the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` contains full config command. This is the part of config:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
EnvironmentFile=/run/docker_opts.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```